# Line graph using integers on y axis and strings on x axis

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, graph

Given the following array of data, how can I display this data on a graph using d3, similar to the example provided.

#### Data

I have my data in an array of objects, as follows:

```
[
  {
    "key": "Brazil",
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "key": "Denmark",
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "key": "Sweden",
    "value": 8
  },
  {
    "key": "Japan",
    "value": 10
  },
  {
    "key": "Russia",
    "value": 14
  }
]
```

#### End Goal

What I am aiming to achieve:
[image: Example line graph]

#### What I have tried

I guess the most important thing is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
</style>
<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var dataset = [
  {
    "key": "Brazil",
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "key": "Denmark",
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "key": "Sweden",
    "value": 8
  },
  {
    "key": "Japan",
    "value": 10
  },
  {
    "key": "Russia",
    "value": 14
  }
];


// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// define the line
var valueline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(width / dataset.length); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

// append the svg obgect to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


function draw(data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.key = d.key.toString();
        d.value = +d.value;
    });

    data.sort(function(a, b){
      return a["value"]-b["value"];
    })

  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { d.key; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  // Add the valueline path.
  svg.append("path")
      .data(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", valueline);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // Add the Y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
  }

  // trigger render
  draw(dataset);

</script>
</body>
```

#### Where (I think) the issues are

This code is an amalgamation of several examples I have seen over the past few days, however they all seem to be aimed at a data model containing only numbers and/or dates, e.g. dates along `x` axis and values along `y` axis.

- X and Y variables / functions

Because of this, I think one of the causes for my code not producing a graph is how the `x` and `y` variables are being declared. I have read up on the API reference however this didnt lead me to success.

- Valueline variable / function

Generally I think this looks ok, however because it uses the x & y functions mentioned above (which I dont fully understand), I cant be sure.

- Setting the domains

I think this is another hangover from using various different examples which were tailored towards a a different model of data, but I'm not certain.

#### Summary

So there's a few areas which I think are causing my graph to litterally show nothing but the X & Y axis, however having spent some considerable time trying to better understand d3 (using examples which dont seem to help), I thought I'd turn to stackoverflow. If you guys can give me any pointers that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your current approach is that your x axis contains a **categorical** (qualitative) variable, not a continuous (quantitative) one.

That being said, you have to choose the adequate scale, such as a point scale:

```
var x = d3.scalePoint()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.key; }));
```

Then, use `d.key` in the line generator.

Finally, use `datum` to append the `<path>`, not `data`.

Here is the code with those changes (and a smaller SVG):

```js
var dataset = [{
    "key": "Brazil",
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "key": "Denmark",
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "key": "Sweden",
    "value": 8
  },
  {
    "key": "Japan",
    "value": 10
  },
  {
    "key": "Russia",
    "value": 14
  }
];


// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scalePoint().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// define the line
var valueline = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.key);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  });

// append the svg obgect to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


function draw(data) {

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.value = +d.value;
  });

  data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.value - b.value;
  })

  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.key;
  }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.value;
  })]);

  // Add the valueline path.
  svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", valueline);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // Add the Y Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
}

// trigger render
draw(dataset);
```

```css
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```